# Variable from enclosing block becomes null in anonymous function

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, null, anonymous-function

```
var client = new WebClient();
var bytes = client.DownloadData(webUrl); // <-- NOT null

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes); // <-- null
    img.EndInit();
    img_DownloadCompleted(img, webUrl);
}));

bytes = null; // EDIT: This last line is what I did wrong. This line
              // of code is executed in PARALLEL with the anonymous 
              // function, and thus this variable is set to null
              // sometime while (or before) the lambda is executing.
```

The above code is executed in a thread as to avoid blocking the UI.

I am trying to download an image from the internet into a `BitmapImage` object. The image is downloaded correctly, but when I try to use it in my UI (using `Dispatcher.Invoke`) I get this error message: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

So I added code that creates the image on the UI thread. But now, when the code reaches the line indicated with `<-- null` the variable `bytes` has suddenly become null. It is not null before the execution proceeds into the anonymous function. (I checked with the debugger)

Does anyone know why this is? Google is not very helpful.

Changing the variable type of `bytes` to `var` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The snippet provides no hint whatsoever.  Go back to the original approach, don't forget to call the BitmapImage's Freeze() method so you won't get that exception anymore.

Comment: Thank you! img.Freeze() after the img.EndInit() indeed fixes the underlying problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you are changing `bytes` variable later and hence modifying "captured" value inside the anonymous function. Something like:

```
var bytes = client.DownloadData(webUrl); <-- NOT null
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
 ...  img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes); <-- null
 ...
}
bytes = null; // something like this - because why not?
```

Note that even if code looks like sequential and `img.StreamSource =  ...` is *before* `bytes = null;` line it actually will likely be executed in opposite order (not deterministic as it runs on other thread).

You should be very careful with such captures that will be executed asynchronously later/on other thread. Safer option is to create anonymous function inside separate method so you can't change captured variables later:

```
Action CreateBitmapAction(bytes[] bytes)
{
 return () =>
 {
    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
    img.BeginInit();
    img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    img.EndInit();
    img_DownloadCompleted(img, webUrl);
 };
}

Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(CreateBitmapAction(bytes));
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. On the last line of the method I had `bytes = null;`. I did not know that anonymous methods can be executed out of sequence. In the future I will use your suggestion and put it in a wrapper method. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jan note that "out of sequence" have nothing to do with the fact this is anonymous method - it is really up to function that takes delegate/lambda as argument to decide when (if ever) call provided method. You'll also find similar behavior with LINQ (search for "LINQ lazy evaluation") and event handlers (which somewhat easier to understand - when adding "Click" handler one would not expect handler to be called immediately).

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a closure created for the the method.
it's referencing an object which is outside of it's scope . Alexei's answer will solve the issue.

but if you still wan't to preserve a lambda like syntax in your code you can do the same thing like so :

```
   var bytes = client.DownloadData(webUrl);
   Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action<byte[]>)(b => 
   {
       // draw a pink bunny , or what ever here.   
   }),bytes);
```